# Etymology of "fiamma" in Italian

Tags: phonology, etymology, language-change, italian

I don't speak Italian at all, but I was a bit surprised that the word "flame" in Italian is "fiamma" (IPA: `/ˈfjam.ma/`) (to compare with `flamme` in French, `flamma` in Latin and `llama` in Spanish). My superficial idea is that it went through the following evolution process:

`flamma` -> `fllamma` -> `fiamma`

I guess that Spanish has influenced the `ll` to be pronounced as `j`.

**Question**: Does this guess make sense? If not, how did `fiamma` evolve from `flamma`?

Comment: I don't think there is any need to posit Spanish influence here. Spanish pronouncing <ll> as [j] is itself likely a recent-ish phenomenon, with certain regions still pronouncing it as [ʎ], while this sound change in Italian was completed by the time Dante wrote (for some reason, his best-known work does involve the word *fiamme* a lot!).

Comment: @LjL Thank you! I related Spanish and Italian, but I ignore completely their historical mutual influence. I just learned that the phenomena you mentioned of Spanish is referred as Yeísmo. It seems that modern French has also come through this process (*i.e. fille*). To be honest, I can't hear the difference between [j] and [ʎ].

Comment: @FirminMartin I just came and did not vote here in any way, but be aware that there is nothing about downvoting in the Code of Conduct (it is more about hate speech and related stuff) and that there is no expectation of explaining any downvotes. It often brings retaliations. Instead, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152174/how-to-deal-with-downvotes-without-any-explanation If you hower your mouse over the downvote button, there is an explanation what the button is for. If someone used the button, they used it to signal what the description says. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: What is against the rules is serial downvoting against more of your posts by one person, if you encounter something suspicious, you can contact the site moderators.

Comment: @VladimirF Absolutely agree about the Code of Conduct. I was not saying it's against any rule but was mostly referring to the "If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming" part. I consider it as a guideline and believe that downvoting is not the best way to address neophytes. They may also hover on the "New contributor" indicator and meditate one second or so. Obviously, each site has its own culture, and personally, I prefer a harsh comment than nothing.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are justified here, especially with no explanation, or on a question by a new contributor. Whilst knowledge of how these consonants evolved in the Romance languages may be considered basic by those with some expertise in historical linguistics, there is no sufficiently detailed account somewhere an interested layman would find it (e.g. wikipedia). As such I don't think the question does reflect a lack of research effort. The question is also perfectly clear

Comment: that leaves it being "unhelpful" as a potential justification. Whilst I understand that most regulars on this site may not get much benefit from it, this question seems likely to be helpful to many people with a more casual interest in linguistics who also notice this unintuitive correspondence. Downvoting it also seems to effectively claim there is some minimal knowledge people should have before engaging with the site, and I don't see the benefit in such gatekeeping

Comment: the close votes (justified as "Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage") make no sense whatsoever. This question is not about the grammar or usage of any particular language, but about comparing the evolution of two related languages. Such questions are on topic. Even questions about the evolution of a single language are consistently allowed as on topic. This should be no different

Comment: @Tristan Indeed, if this site was reserved for research-level Q&A (consider *e.g.* cstheory.SE *vs.* cs.SE, or mathoverflow *vs.* math.SE), then this question would be instantly closed, and I would move on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syllable-initial Latin "Xl" clusters, where X is a consonant, regularly become "Xi" in Italian.

Examples:

> platea -> piazza ('square')

> clamare -> chiamare ('call')

> flumen -> fiume ('river')

> glacia -> ghiaccio ('ice')

> blancus -> bianco ('white')

As you surmise, these went through a stage of  /ʎ/ (like Spanish <ll>).

**Edit**: in some contexts, Spanish goes even further, and loses the preceding consonent:

> clamare -> llamar

> plenus -> lleno ('full')

but this is not universal in Spanish the way it is in Italian. Compare

> platea -> plaza

> florem -> flor ('flower' - cf Italian 'fiore').

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the pattern and giving several examples.

Answer (score 0):

See Colin Fine's answer for the Spanish story. There exist some similar consonant-vowel pairs in West Germanic:

```
Standard German l : Austro-Bavarian ɪ
/fal/ : /foɪ/ ("fall" means fall)
/fɔl/ : /fuɪ/ ("voll" = full)
/fyl/ : /fyɪ/ ("füll" = fill)
/va:l/ : /vɔ:ɪ/ ("wahl" = choice)
/vo:l/ : /vo:ɪ/ ("wohl" = well)
...

Standard German l : Alemannic ʊ
/fi:l/ : /fɪ:ʊ/ ("viel" = much)
/ni:l/ : /nɪ:ʊ/ ("Nil" = Nile)
/mɪlç/ : /mɪʊχ/ ("Milch" = milk)
...
```

Comment: The long /l:/s don't exist, though, right?

Comment: I don't see this answer is very relevant. The Romance phenomenon (in Italian, not Spanish, though it happens to a limited degree in Spanish too) is after a consonant.

Comment: phipsgabler, fair point, I wanted to indicate syllable-length consonants here. Speaking for the variety of Standard German spoken where Austro-Bavarian is spoken, this transcription is adequate though.
ColinFine fair enough, I'll see if someone likes the answer and eventually remove it if the users decide to find it irrelevant. I admit it's intended as a background information, not as a direct answer. (addressing the asker's question "how else would such a process happen if not analogous to this Spanish")

Comment: What's a syllable-length consonant? Do you mean the ambisyllabicity it develops in /fɛl.lɛ/? (I'm from Graz, but I think the only time I use long consonants is when I speak Finnish...)

Comment: @purlupar +1 Thanks for the answer, it's still informative and good to know.

Comment: @phipsgabler I think I'm mistaken here, they are not syllable length. But isn't final /l/ (also in Germany German, not only Austria) longer in /fal/ ("Fall") than in /fa:l/ ("fahl")? Please, some phonologist help please.
FirminMartin Great to hear! Welcome.

Comment: According to traditional anaysis, no, AFAIK -- at least there are no minimal pairs (except maybe for some nasals like /hæŋ hæŋː/ _häng! - hängen_ in some varieties). Maybe it's just confusion arising from the spelling. Altough there may be measureable phonetic differences, of course.

Comment: Right. I couldn't believe it and measured my own pronunciation in Praat, result: Same length ... Cheers